# Bash one-liner that shows a running countdown until a DNS update (TTL expiration)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-scripting

I find myself frequently tasked with updating DNS records and needing to know exactly when the refresh will begin (a.k.a TTL expiration). I came up with this bash one-liner that gives me the output I want:

```
$ dig +noall +answer www.google.com | \
> awk '{ print $2 }' | \
> { read secs; echo "`expr $secs / 60`m `expr $secs % 60`s remaining ($secs)"; }
```

output:

```
3m 36s remaining (216)
```

I'd like to be able to wrap the `watch` command around this so that I can leave it running in a terminal and get a live countdown. Something like:

```
$ watch -n 10 "dig +noall +answer www.google.com | \
> awk '{ print $2 }' | \
> { read secs; echo '`expr $secs / 60`m `expr $secs % 60`s remaining ($secs)'; }"
```

But this simply results in a non-functional watch instance followed by:

```
expr: syntax error
```

I am pretty sure this is some kind of piping/quoting problem and I'm not that well-versed on the intricacies. For the sake of portability I'd prefer to keep it as a one-liner vs. resorting to a script that requires saving to disk. Does anyone know the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to avoid using expr. It's rarely used. Instead I've here the version that does exact the same. Not much different than the above:

```
watch -n1 'dig +noall +answer google.com | \ 
 awk "{print \$2}" | \
 { read secs; echo "$((secs / 60 ))m $((secs % 60))s remaining $((secs))";}'
```

Another aproach which can be used using `tmux` or `screen`

```
    while sleep 1; do dig +noall +answer google.com | \ 
   { while read -r secs; do echo "$((secs / 60 ))m $((secs % 60))s remaining $((secs)) seconds"; done < <(awk '{print $2}' | \
   head -n1 ); };  done
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this! (and to the others who posted answers). Works a treat!

Comment: The double parentheses around `$secs` at the end serve no purpose.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson,  Since arithmetic operations in bash happens within (()) and since $(()) evaluates an arithmetic operations, using $((secs)) isn't that weird. When it comes to $((secs)) of course we could have written it as in $secs. None would have heart in this case. $((secs)) is probably more a habit rather than style.

Comment: `time { a=345; for i in {0..1000000}; do echo "$((a))"; done > /dev/null; }` is about 20% faster if you remove the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error problem, because you forgot to escape the `backstick` character, the `double quote` character. And remember to escape `dollar sign` also, for the value of $secs is passed to `expr`, if you don't, there is no output to stdout:

```
watch -n 10 "dig +noall +answer www.google.com | \
awk '{print\$2}' | \
{ read secs; echo \"\`expr \$secs / 60\`m \`expr \$secs % 60\`s remaining (\$secs)\"; }"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not let AWK do the math and printing?

```
watch -n 10 'dig +noall +answer google.com | awk '\''{print int($2 / 60) "m", $2 % 60 "s remaining", "(" $2 ")"; exit}'\'''
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.

```
watch -n 10 "dig +noall +answer www.google.com | \
 awk '{print \$2}' | \
 { read secs; echo \"\$((\$secs / 60))m \$((\$secs % 60))s remaining\"; }"
```

or alternatively quoted to avoid quite that much mess:

```
watch -n 1 'dig +noall +answer www.google.com | \
 awk "{print \$2}" | \
 { read secs; echo "$(($secs / 60))m $(($secs % 60))s remaining"; }'
```